# Restrictions on exponent laws

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, roots, exponentiation, radicals

Alright, so i want to add restrictions to this list of exponent laws. The code i will post now is **my attempt at writing their restrictions and the laws i want to write restrictions on. SO, please let me know if my attempt is correct and if it's not i would like to see how to write them correctly.**

For all $\mathbf{a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}}$, for all $\mathbf{d,d'\neq 0}$
$$d^b\cdot d^c=d^{b+c}$$
$$(d^b)^c=d^{bc}$$
$$(d \cdot d')^c=d^cd'^c$$
$$\left(\frac{d'}{d}\right)^b=\frac{d'^b}{d^b}$$
$$\frac{d^a}{d^b}=d^{a-b}$$
$$d^{-a}=\frac{1}{d^a}$$
$$a^{\frac{b}{d}}=\begin{cases} \sqrt[d]{a^b} & \text{if d is odd}\\ \sqrt[d]{a^b}, & a\geq 0, \text{if d is even} \end{cases}$$
$$\sqrt[d]{ab}=\sqrt[d]{a}\sqrt[d]{b},\quad\text{where} \textbf{ both } \text{a and b are non-negative}$$
$$\sqrt[d]{\frac{a}{d'}}=\frac{\sqrt[d]{a}}{\sqrt[d]{d'}},\quad\text{where} \textbf{ both } \text{a and d' are non-negative}$$
$$\sqrt[d]{\sqrt[d']{a}}=\sqrt[dd']{a}$$

Answer (score 1):

There's a mistake on the first line. The statement $d^a=d^b \implies a=b$ is not true. For the other statements, there are cases when $a$ or $b$ are zero and the exponents are negative, resulting in cases where the expression is not defined.

Comment: how come d=1 isn't valid?

Comment: Clearly 1^a = 1^b does not imply a=b.

Comment: and with that edit, should i add d,d' greater than 0 too?

Comment: i don't see it clearly, for example 1^x=1^2, x=2, is true and it satisfies it. 1^2=1^2

Comment: Consider 1^9999 = 1^1.

Comment: oh hm, but then how should i list that when for example you have 2^x=2^(1-x), x=1/2 and it satisfies it 2^(1/2)=2^(1-1/2) hence 2^(1/2)=2^(1/2)

Comment: i edited it, is it now fully correct?

Comment: WAIT BUT 1^9999=1^1 it is true!

Comment: Yes but 9999 is not 1...

Comment: oh that's true.

Comment: and are the rest of the things correct now? i edited it when you told me about the negative numbers on the exponents while bases being 0.